# Why is aptitude broken after trying to install python-pip?

Tags: linux, debian, python, aptitude

I'm trying to get pip working for python 3.6 on my debian machine and thought that python-pip would work in the case of `python3.6 pip -V` as python 3.6 couldn't find the pip installation of python3-pip. After I removed python3-pip and python3-pip-whl, I ran `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, and it gave me an error and only partly installed. I ran `sudo apt-get remove python-pip`, and it just gives me this error:

```
(Reading database ... 106170 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-pip (9.0.1-2) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I tried to run `python3.6 get-pip.py` after running `sudo apt-get remove python-pip`, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20649, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

And when I try running `sudo apt-get install zlibc` to fix it, it gives me a [massive error](https://gist.github.com/Polokniko/e594efd587c026763f679fa7f6e37ad7). I installed python 3.6 using [GAD3R's method here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/281411) as I believe that's also a part of the whole issue. Could I fix the problem that I have caused, and if I can't fix it, when I start over again on debian, what should I do, in the case of installing python 3.6 and pip for it? Also, please notify me if you're not understanding a part of my question or if I need to include more information in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `python3-pip` is a buggy package ,if you are using python3 as default in your system you should not install the `python3-pip` until the bug will be fixed.

Install `apt-listbugs` on your system to keep tracking the `python3-pip` bug or visit  [python3-pip: pip fails to import #896390](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896390)

```
apt install apt-listbugs
apt-listbugs list python3-pip
```

sample output:

```
Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
serious bugs of python3-pip (-> ) <Resolved in some Version>
 b1 - #896390 - python3-pip: pip fails to import (Fixed: python-pip/9.0.1-2.1)
Summary:
 python3-pip(1 bug)
```

The buggy package will break your `apt` (`aptitude`) when using the `python3` as default.

A fix is released for `python-pip` ([message #10 bug=896390#10](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896390#10))

> From: Matthias Klose
>
> To: 896390-close@bugs.debian.org
>
> Subject: Bug#896390: fixed in python-pip 9.0.1-2.1
>
> Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 06:56:32 +0000

To solve the broken `apt` you should switch back to `python2.7` version (follow the [update part on this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/153195) to add a multiple python version and switch between them) :

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

set python2.7 as default then remove `python3-pip`:

```
apt purge --autoremove python3-pip
```

Comment: Nice! I just now marked it as the solution.